# Cancel Shipstation API Issue PHP

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to cancel the order from Shipstation for That I've write a code

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/".$order_id,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "DELETE",
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$public_key:$private_key",
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;
        echo "here";
```

now when I run this API it returns nothing no error no issue no success message same order is also not deleted from Shipstation when I try to pass wrong Public or Private key then it gives me an Error
`401 Unauthorized`
it means that API call is going correctly because I'm getting response but when I pass the correct creds then it gives no response.
**Edit**
Now I'm trying

```
$curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/".$order_id,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "DELETE",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Host: ssapi.shipstation.com",
                "Authorization:Basic __MY_AUTH_HERE__",
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;
```

Now it is giving me an Error
`{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`
where I've created my Auth like
`$auth = base64_encode($username_api_key.":". $password_api_secret);`
What is the issue and how to fix that?
Thanks